# React Typescript MaterialUI Paper 'background of undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui, react-typescript

Everytime I add

```
<Paper elevation={0} />
```

to my react component I recieve

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'background')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'background')
```

I do not know how to fix this error and I would really like to use this

here is the full source code

```
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

const Page: FC = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Paper elevation={0} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might be occurring because the Paper component of Material UI. As you are trying to access a background property that is not defined. To fix this error, you can try pasing a sx prop to the Paper component to define the background property.

Here's an example of how the eeror can be fixed by setting the sx prop:

```
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

const Page: FC = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Paper elevation={0} sx={{ background: 'white' }} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Like in the above example, ive added the sx prop to set the background property to white. You can replace white with any other valid CSS color value to set a different background color.

**

> Note

**
the sx prop is a shorthand for defining inline styles using the styled-system library. You may also define the styles using plain CSS in a separate CSS file and apply the class name to the Paper component using the className prop.

Answer (score 0):

fixed with wrapping it in a themeprovider

```
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {}
});

const Page: FC = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
             <Paper elevation={0} sx={{ background: 'white' }} />
          </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Page;
```